# set timeout in httprequest android

Tags: android, httpclient, httpresponse

I am using the following code to get data from the server with http request.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String URL = urlGenerator();

    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(URL); 
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url.toString());

    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
    int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    if(status == 200){
            ...
            }
```

Its working fine.But in case if the phone is connected to wifi or gprs 3g but internet is not working or internet connection is not there, i want to use the timeout feature in the above code.

say after 3 sec i want to show timeout please try again.. 
how do i do that.
in case of time out i want to show a text in the textviw connection timeout .. how do i do that
please help

Answer (score 3):

use this code to accomplish your task

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 30000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 30000);
```

Comment: how do i know that time out happened .. i mean to say .. in case of time out i want to print a message "check your connection" how do i do that