# I am Continously uploading images to s3 from Android app some are successfully uploaded but some images are getting failed to upload

Tags: android, file-upload, amazon-s3

What actually i do in my application is capture the image, Save it to disk and then upload it to s3.

My code to upload is

```
public void credentialsProvider(){

        // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
        CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                getApplicationContext(),
                "ap-south-1:---------------", // Identity Pool ID
                Regions.AP_SOUTH_1  // Region
        );

        setAmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
    }

    /**
     *  Create a AmazonS3Client constructor and pass the credentialsProvider.
     * @param credentialsProvider
     */
    public void setAmazonS3Client(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider){

        // Create an S3 client
        s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);

        // Set the region of your S3 bucket
        s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1));


    }

    public void setTransferUtility(){

        transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getApplicationContext());
    }

    /**
     * This method is used to upload the file to S3 by using TransferUtility class
     *
     */
    public void fileUpload(){

        TransferObserver transferObserver = transferUtility.upload(
                "train-faces",     /* The bucket to upload to */
                time1+date1+"_"+"1" + "_pic.jpg",    /* The key for the uploaded object */
                fileToUpload       /* The file where the data to upload exists */
        );

        transferObserverListener(transferObserver);
    }



    /**
     * This is listener method of the TransferObserver
     * Within this listener method, we get status of uploading and downloading file,
     * to display percentage of the part of file to be uploaded or downloaded to S3
     * It displays an error, when there is a problem in  uploading or downloading file to or from S3.
     * @param transferObserver
     */

    public void transferObserverListener(TransferObserver transferObserver){

        transferObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener(){

            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                if (state.COMPLETED.equals(transferObserver.getState())) {
                    Toast.makeText(CameraService.this, "File Upload Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    fileToUpload.delete();
                }
                Log.e(TAG, "statechange"+state+"");
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                int percentage = (int) (bytesCurrent/bytesTotal * 100);
                Log.e(TAG,"percentage"+percentage +"");
                if (percentage==100){
                    //fileToUpload.delete();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                Log.e(TAG,"error"+"error");

            }

        });
    }
```

When the image is saved, i just call fileUpload() sometimes images are getting uploaded successfully some times i get:
Failed to upload due to unable to execute Http request 7 unable to resolve host no address associated with hostname

I want to make it more reliable and avoid this few failures of upload in my application how to achieve this.

Comment: I think it's kind network issue have you test on wifi or mobile data ?

Comment: i have tested in both case(WiFi & mobile data) success rate is more when using mobile data.

Comment: @HareshChhelana if i upload 150 images 50 are getting failed.

Comment: Will you please share your logcat?

Comment: @HemantParmar i am getting this error when i connect to wifi : Failed to upload: 196 due to Unable to execute HTTP request: Read timed out

Comment: ok so whenever multiple image uploading some images have large bitmap so in pool some images not uploading due to large file and http request is time out. so increase HTTP time out request .

Comment: @AbhiKanimilli have look ,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207265/set-timeout-in-httprequest-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't encountered the `7 unable to resolve host no address associated with hostname` error but this generally occurs when there is a network issue, as mentioned by Hemant.

Regarding the read time out error `Failed to upload: 196 due to Unable to execute HTTP request: Read timed out`, this may or may not be a network issue. Of course, a bad network can definitely cause this but there were known issues with `TransferUtility` which showed some uploads as failed even when there were no network issues.

If it is a genuine network issue, increasing the socket timeout as suggested may fix/reduce the errors.

```
ClientConfiguration cc = new ClientConfiguration(); 
cc.setSocketTimeout(120000); AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider, cc);
```

Set the timeout to some high value as per your preference. If this does not fix or reduce the errors & you are sure there are no network issues then this may be a problem with the `TransferUtility` itself. Users mentioned that uploading large files directly results in this error and a workaround used by one person was to upload a 1 Kb dummy file prior to any upload but this is obviously not a solution. See [this post](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/94) for details. I personally have faced this error only with bad network so I can't verify if the workarounds are effective or not and whether the issue has been fixed in a later release of SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue when the internet is not stable, but after making configuration changes it works.

```
  val configuration = ClientConfiguration()
        configuration.maxErrorRetry = 10
        configuration.maxConnections = 100
        configuration.connectionTimeout = 0
        configuration.socketTimeout = 0
  val s3Client = AmazonS3Client(credentials,configuration)
```